# ROS Answers SE migration: p2os teleop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ros fuerte, pioneer 3dx robot and p2os(even though there's no version of p2os for ros fuerte, p2os works and i can publish cmd to robot - robot moves)..

so I need to use the joystick and to move robot manually. When I launch the teleop_joy.launch, it works well and it seems that connection is established, but pioneer doesn't move.

Since it didn't work, I've found this question *http://answers.ros.org/question/39962/problem-with-p2os-teleop/* and did the remaping part in teleop_joy.launch:

*remap from="/p2os_teleop/cmd_vel" to="/cmd_vel"*

*remap from="/p2os_teleop/joy" to ="/joy"*

Again it didn't work. I also tried to include teleop_joy.launch in p2os.launch file, and again, connection is established and everyhing seems ok, but robot still dosen't move.. :/
when I call rxgraph function, I can see that cmd_vel is published from /p2os_teleop to /p2os driver.

any idea what else to do?
thank you in advance for your help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43329/p2os-teleop/) by [em](https://answers.ros.org/users/3138/em/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It usually helps to use [rostopic echo](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo) or [rostopic hz](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_hz) to confirm that data are actually being published on all your topics of interest.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [em](https://answers.ros.org/users/3138/em/) on 2012-09-11**:
I've checked that also, but didn't help - everything seemed fine.. One friend of mine helped me, the problem was with hardvare-the joystick wasn't compatible :/ anyway, it works now :)